# ssh with auto login and running ./filecommand.py (how do i get it to echo commands of the script)

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, python, auto-login

I have created a Linux mint launcher (shortcut)  in the launcher the command  is:

ssh user@192.168.1.100 ./lamp.py

When I double click the launcher it opens the terminal window and doesn't show me the command(light on)&(light off) but the lamp lights up & turns off.     The shortcut works but will not display(echo, print, printf) the command.

( I want it to show the command light on, and then light off)

Now if I log in as:

ssh user@192.168.1.100
it opens the terminal prompt I type ./lamp.py it will show me the command lamp on, then lamp off

I need help trying to figure out on launcher with exe file ./lamp.py to display or echo commands.  any ideas?  I have tried all methods of echo and no luck it will not show me the python file print commands

Answer (score 0):

There are two main differences between issuing commands via arguments (`ssh USER@HOST COMMAND...`) and commands issued interactively in a terminal:

- the remote shell is not marked interactive (login)
- there is no [p]tty created

I don't know the exact nature of what you are are expecting, but I'm going to guess that the `lamp.py` script changes what output it generates without one or both of those.  If I had to guess, I'd guess that it's checking for a tty.  Try adding `-t` to your ssh command:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.100 -t ./lamp.py
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to resort to explicitly starting a login shell, which calls `lamp.py`:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.100 -t 'bash -ic "./lamp.py"'
```